# Why can't a list of Interfaces use an implementing type?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

There must be something fundamental about interfaces/generics I have not yet learned.  I hope to learn it now.

Here is the scenario:

I have this interface and class:

```
public interface IInterface
{
    string TestValue { get; set; }
}

public class RealValue: IInterface
{
    public string TestValue { get; set; }
}
```

If I create a method like this it compiles just fine:

```
public class RandomTest: IMethodInterface
{
   public IInterface GetRealValue()
   {
       RealValue realValue = new RealValue();
       return realValue;
   }
 }
```

Note that I am returning an object that implements the interface.

Now, if I add to the `RandomTest` class a method that returns list then it does not work anymore:

```
 public List<IInterface> GetRealValues()
 {
    List<RealValue> realValues = new List<RealValue>();
    return realValues;  // ERROR Here <- says it can't convert to a List<IInterface>
 }
```

So, my guess is that generics can't figure this out, but why?

Is there a way around this?  What do you do when the return value of the method above is locked because you are implementing an interface like this:

```
public interface IMethodInterface
{
    IInterface GetRealValue();
    List<IInterface> GetRealValues(); // Can't just convert the return types to a concrete 
                                      // class because I am implementing this.  This 
                                      // interface is in a separate project that does not 
                                      // have the concrete classes.
}
```

Is there any hope?  What would you do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason for this is that `List<RealValue>` is a specific type, which does not inherit `List<IInterface>`, so it cannot be converted.

However, in .NET 4.0 you're in luck. The interface `IEnumerable<out T>` specifies that `T` can be the class, or a base class, so you can change your method to:

```
IEnumerable<IInterface> GetRealValues();
```

on .NET 4.0. Note that this only works because `IEnumerable` has the `out` keyword specified on the template parameter.

The `out` keyword means two things:

1. The type before which you put the `out` keyword can only be used for types that go out of the class. So, `public T MyMethod()` is allowed, but `public void MyMethod(T myParam)` is not allowed, because this goes into the class;
2. Because of this restriction, .NET knows that `T` can be cased to everything that inherits from `T`. Because of the restriction, this is guaranteed to be a safe operation.

Comment: This looks nice.  I will have to dig more to understand what `out` means for a generic type param.  Either way, I tried it and it worked.

Comment: Expanded the answer with a little bit more info concerning the `out` keyword.

Comment: Sweet!  Thanks for the expanded answer!

Answer (score 4):

Note that if you could convert `List<RealValue>` to `List<IInterface>` you could call `.Add(anyObjectImplementingIInterface)` which cannot work.

You can, however, use `.Cast<IInterface>().ToList()`.

Answer (score 1):

A `List<RealValue>` cannot be used in place of a `List<IInterface>`. If it was permitted, the caller would be able to Add an `IInterface` to the returned list that is of a type other than `RealValue`.